# Display data dynamically to my html page where data come from an api created by me

Tags: javascript, api

this is my get api created at server side with node js

```
app.get('/tasks/tasks', (req, res) => {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM tasks', function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.status(200).send({ success: true, results: result });
    });
});
```

now this is my html section where i want to show all the data inside this

```
<div class="list" id="dragabble_card">
            <h3 class="list-title">Tasks</h3>
            <ul class="list-items" id="parent_1">
                <form action="/tasks" method="POST">
                    <li id="editableLi">
                        <input name="card_name" type="text" id="textboxId" class="input_style" />
                    </li>
                </form>
                <form action="/tasks" method="POST">
                    <li id="editableLi">
                        <input name="card_name" type="text" id="textboxId" class="input_style" />
                    </li>
                </form>
                <form action="/tasks" method="POST">
                    <li id="editableLi">
                        <input name="card_name" type="text" id="textboxId" class="input_style" /> </li>
                </form>
            </ul>
            <button class="add-card-btn btn" onclick="createEditableLi('parent_1')">Add a card</button>
        </div>
```

i want to put my data inside input tag or either create a new

to show the data

Comment: You can use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to get the data and then use [template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) for formating.

Comment: i am tryin this var url = "http://localhost:3000/tasks/tasks"; // Change this to your URL
fetch(url)
    .then(function (response) {
        if (response.ok) {
            response.json().then(function (data) {
                
            });
        } else {
            console.log("response failed?");
        }
    });

Comment: but don't know how to show that data in html

Comment: Have you looked at the example for template that I linked in my first comment? There is an example of how to use templates and assign values there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show dynamic data to html there is an easy way,

```
var dynamicElement = '<div>Or Other tag then '+results.Something or result[0].something +'\
<h1>'+result.something or result[1].something+'\
';
```

then append that dynamicElement with you static html tag

```
$('#youId').append(dynamicElement)
```